# See the page outlines

Tags: html, firefox

Is there a tool that allows to see the whole page oulined in the browser? For example, I have a lot of hidden divs or images, may be overflown by some other elements and I want to see all the elements outlined, just to see what is placed in what place. If you ever used Adobe Illustrator, you could understand what I mean if you switched to outlines mode there by clicking CTRL+Y. I use FireBug now for something like that, but may be there is something more advanced for that?

Comment: webdeveloper plugin (for firefox) maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [Web Developer add-on for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/).

It has plenty of tools for this kind of stuff. Although not one exactly as the outline-mode in Illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 Developer Tools has a "show all DIV elements" option. Press F-12 to open the developer tools window.

Answer (score 1):

I love Firebug plug-in for Firefox. Firebug allows you to navigate around the page, and it will highlight the element you've selected. It's a very powerful tool and it makes it very easy to see how your site hangs together. Plus it's got loads of other debugging tools built into it. If you're developing web sites, you should be using Firebug.

There are similar tools available for other browsers. Recent versions of IE have the "developers tools" built in, though it's not as easy to use or as powerful as Firebug. Chrome and Safari also have a Developers Tools feature, which is quite powerful. Personally I still prefer Firebug, but they are all useful tools.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Web-developer on fire-fox has been very helpful for me. I particularly like the outline block elements which has been helpful for me building sound structures and see how my elements are lining up as I go, and view style information that allows you to hover over all of your elements and see the css path.

It sounds like outline block elements would be what you are looking for.